# SSL HandShake Error querying Twitter API with Python httplib2/oauth2

Tags: ssl, twitter, oauth-2.0, httplib2

I am authenticating to Twitter in Python with Ouath2 and querying the Twitter API using a Client object (this automatically signs the requests, it is an extension of httplib2)

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
import oauth2 as oauth

# authenticate
consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
token = oauth.Token(token_key, token_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

# request url
info, data = client.request('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=50&max_id=999999999999999999&screen_name=audiuk&since_id=643822673450168322', 'GET')
print data
```

On my local environment this works fine, in production I get this error:

```
2015-09-22 15:19:42 ERROR    SSLHandshakeError ([SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)) encountered for https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=50&max_id=999999999999999999&screen_name=audiuk&since_id=643822673450168322, aborting
```

I am using Python 2.7.9.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that httplib2 certificates are expired, in your deployed version (it happened to me too)
If you don't want to update the whole library, like me, try replacing cacerts.txt with [last version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jcgregorio/httplib2/master/python2/httplib2/cacerts.txt)

1- Get path where you have this file:

```
>>> import httplib2
>>> httplib2.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.pyc'
```

2- Mv into directory and rename old cacerts.txt

```
mv cacerts.txt cacerts.txt.old
```

3- Get new version and enjoy with oauth2

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jcgregorio/httplib2/master/python2/httplib2/cacerts.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

please upgrade httplib2.

```
# pip install httplib2 --upgrade
```

Comment: You could improve the answer with even a line about **why** this will fix the issue...